# warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

Tags: c++

Warning in below line

```
for(int nPort = 0 ; nPort< (sizeof(nArrOverloadParams)/sizeof(int)) && nRetVal 
                    == RET_SUCCESS_VALUE ;nPort++)
```

Comment: `sizeof()` yields an unsigned value, so what's unclear about the warning? Change to `unsigned int nPort = 0;`

Comment: When asking a question, it's usually a good idea to ask your question.

Comment: I have to try to earn the Reversal badge!!!

Answer (score 0):

The warning indicates that the comparison in principle *could* fail. The signed value is <sup>(1)</sup>promoted to the unsigned type. And if it's negative (the compiler doesn't know that it isn't, without extensive analysis) then the promotion to unsigned produces a very large value.

A consequence is that you're *guaranteed* that

```
std::string( "Blah" ).length() < -5
```

which is just extremely silly – it's a consequence of a choice of type for size values that once made sense, but that that currently is pretty sub-optimal (but impossible to change due to the need for compatibility).

As a rule of thumb it's therefore a good idea to

- use signed types for numbers, but
- use unsigned types for bit level operations.

E.g. you can use `ptrdiff_t`, the type of the result of a pointer difference expression, as a signed version of `size_t`.

Then you can express a signed size function for arrays as e.g.

```
#include <stddef.h>

namespace cppx {
    using Size = ptrdiff_t;

    template< class Item, Size n >
    auto n_items( Item (&)[n] )
        -> Size
    { return n; }
}
```

and the relevant part of the loop then becomes

```
using cppx::n_items;

int overloadedParams[77];
for( int port = 0 ; port< n_items( overloadedParams ); port++ )
```

---

An alternative is to use a *range-based loop*, bypassing the entire issue:

```
for( int param : overloadedParams )
```

If the index is needed for the loop body's logic then a counter can be added.

The behavior of the loop is defined in terms of equivalent code expressed in terms of `std::begin` and `std::end`.

---

History. As far as I know it was Dietmar Kuhl who identified the triad of functions `begin`, `end` and `n_items` as practically useful (it's the necessary support for signed size programming), although not with that name for the third function. The C++11 standard added `std::begin` and `std::end`, but no `std::n_items` (`std::extent` is a very different beast).

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> In the standard this conversion is part of the **“usual arithmetic conversions”** defined by C++14 §5/10.</sup>